# 301 redirect index.html to index.php and hide index.php from the url

Tags: redirect

I change recently my website pages to .php
Before I had a rewrite rule to shown example.com/index.html as example.com/

Now I want the same but with the redirect to index.php

I try something but I ended with a loop..
What is the correct way to do it?
All this is to prevent google to take the index.php as a new page instead an evolution of index.html
I want to make all this with htaccess, I already did it for each of the other pages on this way:

Redirect 301 /old-url-name.html http://www.example.com/new-url-name.php

Also.. there is a way to hide all index.php from their respective folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent Google from indexing both urls you must use the [canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) meta tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

Redirecting from index.php is not needed, just don't link the index.php page anywhere in your site. In other words, replace this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/index.php">Home</a>
```

with this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/">Home</a>
```

Comment: But I delete my old htmls, I read that the right way to do it is with 301 redirect.  The link example is a good tip, thanks